# How to set the speed of a single mouse click

Tags: 14.04, mouse, settings

If you do a slow single click on a unit launch icon or a menu item in the taskbar Ubuntu interprets this as a move rather than an open command.

I would like to increase the time threshold at which an open becomes a move.

The mouse setting allows the setting of the double click speed, how do I set the single click speed?

Terry

Answer (score 0):

I sure would like to change mine to ~2000ms (2 seconds). I am on LXDE.

:)

I figured it out.  Just follow this procedure for Lubuntu (LXDE) 14.04 - https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/lubuntu:

-From Terminal in your HOME directory(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

- Create a hidden configuration file:
  touch ~/.gtkrc-2.0
- Open the newly created text file with Leafpad.
- Copy/paste the following line into the text file:
  gtk-double-click-time=2000
- Save the file and close it.
- Log out

Comment: I figured it out.  Just follow this procedure for Lubuntu (LXDE) 14.04:

Comment: Looks like this is about *double* click, while the question is about *single* click.